# Is it possible to use a specific event in calculated metrics in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting up a report based on a calculated metric in Google Analytics. I would like to divide the total number of a specific event action with the number of users. Something similar to:

```
{{Total Events (MyEventCategory / MyEventAction)}} / {{Users}}
```

I have tried to find documentation on this feature. The autosuggestion when creating the calculated metric do not suggest the above is possible, but I would like to shout out and hear if anyone out there know whether or not this is possible.

Comment: You can create a custom metric that is incremented with your specific event. Custom metrics can be used in calculated metrics. In any case I'm not sure this is on-topic since it is a configuration option, not a coding question (still a good question, though).

Comment: What I actually ended up doing was using the Google Analytics plugin for Google Docs and imported the data from the API and calculated my metrics there instead of in the Google Analytics reporting UI